# How do i redirect my website to mobile site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, mobile

We have a website called www.domain.com. We need to redirect mobile customers into m.domain.com. I added some rules but right now  all the request from mobile is going to m.domain.com. But we don't want this.Eg: www.domain.com/reports this should not go to m.domain.com instead this should go to www.domain.com/reports itself.How can i make this happen ?

Here is the code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)noredirect=0(&|$) 
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:m.domain.com/] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\. 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)noredirect=0(&|$) 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mredir=0.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ m.domain.com [L]
```

Comment: Please post you current code - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Sumesh: Can you post your current .htaccess?

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)noredirect=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:http://m.domain.com/]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)noredirect=0(&|$)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mredir=0.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.domain.com/ [L]

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the "http://" in your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ m.domain.com [L]
```

needs

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.domain.com/ [L,R]
```

Comment: But this will go to m.domain.com/reports...i need to open this on mobile like domain.com/reports.Only http:domain.com should redirect to m.domain.com...rest all should go to desktop version